# AngularJS - Switch between Templates

Tags: php, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently, I have my directives being switched out in this fashion.

In my directive:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    var controller = ['$scope', function ($scope) {

      }];

    angular
        .module('moduleName', ['myDependency'])
        .directive('dirName', function($compile, $window){
            return{
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                require: [ '^?myDependency'],
                scope: false,
                controller: controller ,
                template:
                `<div ng-switch="templateConfig.type">
                   <div ng-switch-when='con1'>
                     <p> Config 1 </p>
                   </div>
                   <div ng-switch-when='con2'>
                     <p> Config 2 </p>
                   </div>
                   <div ng-switch-when='con3'>
                     <p> Config 3 </p>
                   </div>
                 </div>`
```

And in the PHP file, I have the following:

```
function pageController($scope, $http, $filter, $cleo, $timeout, $compile) {
    $scope.templateConfig= {type: 'Con2'};
}
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span1" id="title" > name </div>
            <div class="span11">
                <dirName>
                </dirName>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span1" id="title" > name2 </div>
            <div class="span11">
                <dirName>
                </dirName>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So how it works is that when I can switch between templates using  `{type: 'Con2'}.` However, this will affect both `<dirName></dirName>` tags. What I want is for me to have the ability to define them independently of each other.

What I want would be something like `<dirName templateConfig=Con1></dirName>`. I not entirely sure how to achieve this though but I don't think it should be too difficult to make the switch.

Also, I did leave out a lot of code from the PHP file and changed the original names in the code but none of that should be relevant.

Comment: A side note: It may be worth looking up component-based angular (1.5+, then just move on up to 2+ once you understand it) instead of using old school directives. Makes things like this a little more easily reasoned about. Not to mention, it's kinda just how frontend work has been moving in the last couple years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function form of the `template` property:

```
app.directive('dirName', function($compile, $window){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: function (elem, attrs) {
            switch(attrs.templateConfig) {
                case 'con1':
                  return `<p> Config 1 </p>`;
                case 'con2':
                  return `<p> Config 2 </p>`;
                case 'con3':
                  return `<p> Config 3 </p>`;
             };
         }
     };
})
```

Example usage:

```
<dir-name template-config="con2">
</dir-name>
```

---

## Update

From the Docs:

> ### template
>
> Value may be:
>
> - A function which takes two arguments `tElement` and `tAttrs` (described in the `compile` function api below) and returns a string value.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-template-)

Comment: Got it to work but I needed to make a modification from your original code. The first is to add `scope:{templateConfig: '='}`, .The other was to change `switch(attrs.templateConfig) {` to `switch (scope.attr('template-config')){`. It seemed to work perfectly after those changes. Thanks!

Comment: Please notice that the template function does not have `scope` as one of its arguments. It is `template: function (tElem, tAttrs)`.